# 220 volt, three phase issue

Tags: voltage, motor, wiring, three-phase, phase

My company had a machine moved from one facility to another.

The machine was fully operational when it was disconnected. It operates on 220V three phase power.

When powered up at the new facility the machine will not run.

Checked incoming power with the disconnect off and there is 220 on all three legs.
Turned disconnect on and read 220 across L1, L2, & L3, as expected.
When checking to ground L1 & L2 read 220, L3 has no voltage.

What would cause this?

Comment: Consider to write the observations without vaque spoken language terms like "with disconnect off", "on a leg" and"across Lx". For example I do not have a slightest idea what actual connections and measurements they exactly mean. Draw an exact schematic which shows exact measurement connections in different cases. Tell also where this happened. Mains AC electricity is delivered differently in different countries. Inside a country there can also be large variations. A competent and qualified local electrician would solve the problem or at least finds what should be fixed in minutes. Hire one.

Comment: Phase rotation the same at new facility as was at old location?

Comment: What part of the world are you in?  Was the old location "delta" or "wye" wired?  What was the voltage pole-pole?  Same question new location.

Comment: @vu2nan How did you got yourself confirmed that editing 120 to 220 is in accordance with questioner's measurement results?

Comment: @user287001 - Hi, When the voltage is 220 V after the disconnect switch it cannot be 120 V before it.

Comment: Interesting. I red that when the connection to the electricity was ON (=disconnect was OFF) the voltage had dropped to 120 unknown units. With no the actual circuit presenting schematic this is only a guess.

Comment: @user287001 - Hi, A mains disconnect switch would have a knob with 'ON' and 'OFF' positions marked. With the pointer in the 'OFF' position the switch would be open and in the 'ON' position it would be closed.

Comment: That's as possible truth as numerous possible new terms and new meanings of common engineering terms that the questioner surely is able to invent and use without revealing his inventions as proper schematics.

Answer (score 1):

> When checking to ground L1 & L2 read 220, L3 has no voltage.

It appears that your new facility has a 220 V 'Corner-grounded Delta' system as that alone would demonstrate the above quoted characteristic.

[image]

However, further troubleshooting would be required to ascertain the cause of your machine being inoperative.

Answer (score 0):

> When checking to ground L1 & L2 read 220, L3 has no voltage.

That looks like there are just two phases connected.

Also make sure that they're actually different phases connected. You should read ~380 V *in between* phases (220 V * √3).